# UI freezing while calling asynchronous AJAX with PhoneGap

Tags: android, iphone, ajax, cordova, asynchronous

i'm developing a PhoneGap application, it's working fine in my computer browser and in the iOS simulator, but the UI is freezing while calling asynchronous AJAX on devices (iPhone and Android).

For instance, I'm using animated GIF images to show my user that the content is loading, I've got 10 simultaneous calls done, but the UI is waiting the 10 calls to be finished before changing the content of the screen. The problem is that the loading animation is not even done.

This is my ajax call:

```
GetContribution: function(me, id) {

$.ajax({ 
    cache: false, 
    async: true, 
    type: "GET", 
    dataType: "json",
    url: AN_URL,
    data: 'id='+id+'&type=0',
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    accept: "application/json", 
    beforeSend: configureHeader,
    success: function (data) {
        me.set(data.GetContributionResult);
    me.setPZLoaded(true);
        me.grabContributions();
        me.trigger('change');
    },
    error: function (r) {
        console.log(r);
    }
});

},
```

Is there something special to do for asynchronous calls on PhoneGap?

Thanks for your help.

Cyril

Answer (score 0):

So there is no problem with ajax call. The problem is only with the loader for the ajax calls. For that, there is one jquery library for ajax loader. Just try with that. It will solve your problem.
Go through this link,

http://jquery.malsup.com/block/

Comment: I'm already using this lib in my application, but the loaders I'm using here are present in all my cells to show my user that the content is loading. Any other idea?